# Driving Flash ROM Vpp current from GPIO

Tags: transistors, current-source

I'm interfacing a 5V AT90USB128x MCU to either 8MB Intel Strataflash DA28F640-J5A or a 2MB Sharp LH28F160S5NS (both SSOP56)

On the larger Intel chips, pin 56 is VPEN, so only requires the presence of 5V to enable writing, with the programming current pulled from VCC.

On the Sharp chips however, that pin is VPP, and is specced to require 80mA for write operations which is too much for my MCU to provide.

In either case I also have an LED hooked up the GPIO to indicate a write-operation in progress.

I get somewhat lost with transistor circuits.   What would be a suitable circuit to permit my positive logic GPIO output to provide sufficient current?

If I understand correctly it might look somewhat like the second image in [this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/342175/17409).

Comment: (this is a hobby project, and annoyingly I didn't find out about this distinction until after I'd had the prototype PCBs fabricated).

Answer (score 2):

This assumes that your microcontroller supply is 5V, not 3.3V.

If you have control of the code, you may want to switch the sense of the GPIO pin.  For *negative*-true GPIO, use the circuit shown.  I haven't called out the part number for M1 -- choose a small, logic-level, P-channel MOSFET with a RDS_on less that 100m\$\Omega\$, and you should be fine.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fkx0h4.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If, for some reason, you just can't switch the sense of the GPIO pin, precede this with a single-gate inverter, such as a 74HC1G04.